# Why doesn't the Random.Next method in .NET support floats/double?

Tags: c#, .net, math

So maybe I want to have values between -1.0 and 1.0 as floats. It's clumsy having to write this and bolt it on top using extension methods IMO.

Comment: This is not a real question because there is no way for anyone to realistically answer it. Why not ask for a workaround or alternative instead?

Comment: Also the OP's replies to the answers confirm this to be at the very least 'subjective and argumentative'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public static double NextDouble(this Random rnd, double min, double max){
    return rnd.NextDouble() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Call with:

```
double x = rnd.NextDouble(-1, 1);
```

to get a value in the range `-1 <= x < 1`

Answer (score 18):

There's a [`.NextDouble()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble.aspx) method as well that does almost exactly what you want- just 0 to 1.0 instead of -1.0 to 1.0.

Comment: D'oh.  Thats a way better answer +1.

Comment: Thanks, I remembered that now, but it still doesn't support from to, but from 0 to n, which is stil lacking. Why not also have an overload with a to b, right?

Comment: It's not that hard- still just two calls: one to Random.Next() for the integer portion and another to NextDouble() for the mantissa.

Comment: Is there some reason the more canonical (NextDouble() * 2 - 1) doesn't work?  Are all the bits of the mantissa significant in your application?

Comment: I was thinking more for any range, not just -1 to 1, since over a large range a single call wouldn't have the same precision.

Comment: Yes, I meant from n to m, where n can be negative, etc. Also it's in Random(int) but not Random(double) makes me wonder.

Comment: (NextDouble() * (max - min) + min) will work if "mostly random" is random enough.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Random.NextDouble()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble.aspx) method which will produces a random value between 0.0 and 1.0 as @Joel_Coehorn's suggested

I just want to add that, extending the range to -1.0 and 1.0 is a simple calculation

```
var r = new Random();

var randomValue = r.NextDouble() * 2.0 - 1.0
```

Or to generalize it, to extend `NextDouble()` result to any range (a, b), you can do this:

```
var randomValue = r.NextDouble() * (b - a) - a
```

Comment: You wanted to say "..the range to -1.0 and 1.0 is a ..."

Answer (score 3):

Because most of the time, we want an int within a range, so we were provided with methods to do that.  Many languages only support a random method that returns a double between 0.0 and 1.0.  C# provides this functionality in the .NextDouble() method.

This is decent enough design, as it makes the common easy (Rolling a die - myRandom.Next(1,7);) and everthing else possible. - myRandom.NextDouble() * 2.0 - 1.0;

Comment: If you are working with floats then, having a random float generator from -n to n is more useful.

Comment: Then write a one line extension method and use it to your hearts content

Comment: Rolling a die is apparently not easy enough - it's myRandom.Next(1, 7) as the upper limit is exclusive :)

Answer (score 1):

On a side note, I'd have to point out that, at last, the random-number generation algorithm in a framework is not something clumsy (like cstdlib's `rand()`) but actually a good implementation (Park&Miller, IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of random number usage I've seen (in fact all I've ever seen, although apparently in 3 decades of programming I haven't seen much) is generating random integers in a specified range.

Hence Random.Next seems very convenient to me.

Comment: Then you haven't seen much. :) In CG, random floats are very common.

Comment: Anthony, it depends on the type of programming you do. Just because someone programs say for instance databases doesn't mean he has seen all there is to programming. Hence I mentioned CG.

Comment: I wonder how many database style applications there are in the world in total compared to the number of CG apps?

Answer (score 0):

> It's clumsy having to write this and
>   bolt it on top using extension methods

Not really - extension methods are succinct and I'm glad the feature is there for things like this.

Comment: Extension methods are good but you are stuck if the method was a static method as static or a property (static or instance).

Answer (score 0):

This method isn't that hard to add, seems like the perfect usage of an extension method.

```
public double NextSignedDouble(this Random r)
{
    return (r.Next(0, 2) == 0) ? r.NextDouble() : (r.NextDouble() * -1);
}
```